# Similar to Google Maps Snap-To-Road API in HERE Maps

Tags: angular, typescript, here-api

I'm fetching LatLngs from the database and drawing polylines on HERE Maps. Sometimes due to irregular latLngs it draws off the road on the map. Is there any similar to Google Maps Snap-To-Road API to correct the polylines.

Answer (score 1):

Our route matching API does exactly this: takes a list of GPS coordinates and returns the most probable route (so the corrections you are talking about). Please check out the API at:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/route-match/topics/what-is.html

Comment: 404 Not Found...